# Are there succinct listings of extensions implemented by various compilers?

Tags: c++, portability

I've got a section of code inside which I don't care about portability. It's Win32 API ridden code anyway; it serves to suck information out of the OS (which of course requires some form of OS specific API). I'm not intending to ever support things like MinGW either, because such compilers don't implement huge portions of the Windows API (in particular, things like COM stuff).

I therefore don't care about portability for this section, and would be interested in using libraries or language extensions provided by my compiler (currently, MSVC++).

Are there any such listings available for MSVC++ on Windows and GCC on Linux, for example?

Comment: The [GCC extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) are documented as part of the GCC documentation. Also available: [extension allocators](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt04ch11.html#allocator.ext).

Comment: @Kerrek: That covers language enhancements. But not the things that come with POSIX, glibc, and friends.

Comment: @Billy: But those aren't extensions offered by the _compiler_. Those are just libraries you happen to have on your system. They may come along with the compiler, but they are nothing more than libraries, no more special or unique to GCC than any other library you might use.

Comment: Having lived the nightmare that is a mature code base relying on some extension living longer than *the* compiler that supplied the extension, I counsel caution in using these things. *::shudders::*

Comment: @Nicol: I would consider that part of the compiler. ATL is considered part of MSVC++, even though it's a library. From my (or any other programmer's prospective), there is no difference.

Comment: @Billy: except that it _is_ different. ATL is not considered part of VC++; it simply ships with it. In fact, VC 2005 Express didn't even ship it with it; you had to download the Platform SDK to get it. There is a huge difference between a library and a compiler extension. Whether you want to acknowledge that difference is a different matter. They are not the same thing. Indeed, this kind of thinking leads to the idea (that I personally detest) that C++ is the same thing as its standard library, which is how so many people try to measure the utility of a language.

Comment: @Nicol: That's because the libraries one has access to have a huge impact on how productive one is. It's much easier to snap together a set of LEGO bricks than it is to cast one's own. Libraries contribute to the utility of a language; I for one wouldn't like using C++ very much without `vector` and friends. Some libraries, such as the STL, are so pervasive as to define conventions in a language. Yes, technically there is a difference between a language extension and a library. To the user though, there is no effective difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [list of Unix system calls](http://www.unix.org/version3/inttables.pdf) and which standard(s) they belong to very helpful a while back when I was trying to write some fairly conservative and portable C. That sounds like what you're looking for from the comments.

GCC has a list of [C extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html), many of which can be used in C++ code with GCC too. There's also a list of the [C++ extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html) in GCC. Clang has a [similar list also](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).